# Python UDP client-server with different matching incoming-outgoing ports

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, udp

Based on the example at http://www.binarytides.com/programming-udp-sockets-in-python/ I modified it to run on python 3 and used two opposed ports on client and server, so replies from each one go to these ports. Here are my examples

Server:

```
'''
    Simple udp socket server
'''

import socket
import sys

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT_IN = 8889  # Arbitrary non-privileged port
PORT_OUT = 8888

# Datagram (udp) socket
try :
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    print('Socket created')
except socket.error as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit()


# Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT_IN))
except socket.error as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit()

print('Socket bind complete')

#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    # receive data from client (data, addr)
    d = s.recvfrom(1024)
    data = d[0]
    addr = d[1]

    if not data:
        break

    reply = 'OK...' + str(data)

    s.sendto(reply.encode('UTF-8'), ('localhost', PORT_OUT))
    print('Message[' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]) + '] - ' + str(data).strip())

s.close()
```

Client:

```
'''
    udp socket client
    Silver Moon
'''

import socket   #for sockets
import sys  #for exit

# create dgram udp socket
try:
    s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
except socket.error:
    print('Failed to create socket')
    sys.exit()

host = 'localhost'
port_out = 8889
port_in = 8888

counter = 0
while(1) :
    # msg = b'aoua'
    msg = 'aoua' + str(counter)

    try :
        #Set the whole string
        s1.sendto(msg.encode('UTF-8'), (host, port_out))

        # receive data from client (data, addr)
        s2.bind(('localhost', port_in))
        d = s2.recvfrom(1472)
        reply = d[0]
        addr = d[1]

        print('Server reply : ' + str(reply))

    except socket.error as e:
        print(e)
        # sys.exit()
    counter += 1
```

Problem is with the client which cannot receive any response from server and `d = s2.recvfrom(1472)` hangs with error `[WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied`.
I've noticed a slightly different behaviour with `sock.settimeout(seconds)`, but I really can't figure why. Isn't `d = s2.recvfrom(buffer)` supposed to wait for incoming data?
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Damn... Just saw it. Silly mistake. Calling `s2.bind(('localhost', port_in))` in Client inside the loop.